# MyBatis - Invalid bound statement (not found)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mybatis

Начал разбираться с mybatis, но при работе с ним не использую spring.

Проект имеет следующую структуру:

[image: Структура проекта]
Классы Payment и Tariff на данный момент не используются.

Интерфейс **SubscriberMapper.java** имеет следующий вид:

```
public interface SubscriberMapper
{
    Subscriber getSubscriberById(Integer id);

    List getSubscribers();
}
```

Файл **SubscriberMapper.xml** имеет следующий вид:

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper     PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="mapper">

    <select id="getSubscriberById" parameterType="java.lang.Integer">
        select * from subscriber where id = #{id}  
    </select>

    <select id="getSubscribers">
        select * from subscriber
    </select>

</mapper>
```

В файле **mybatis-config.xml** присутствуют строки:

```
<mappers>
    <mapper class="mapper.SubscriberMapper"/>
</mappers>
```

При выполнении последней строки приведенного кода в файле **SubscriberMapper.java**

```
reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis-config.xml");
sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
subscriberMapper = sqlSessionFactory.openSession().getMapper(SubscriberMapper.class); 
Subscriber subscriber = subscriberMapper.getSubscriberById(1);
```

выпадает ошибка **Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): mapper.SubscriberMapper.getSubscriberById**

Я пока, видимо, еще не до конца осознал философию, по которой все это работает.
Оба файла, по идее, и класс называются одинаково, все пути прописаны правильно.
В **pom.xml** прописывал

```
<resources>            
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

И это не помогло.

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, с чем это может быть связано?

Заранее, спасибо!

З.Ы.: Использовал подобную запись интерфейса - программа работает, запросы отправляются.
Полагаю, что проблема действительно в том, что почему-то не находится файл 
 **SubscriberMapper.xml**.
Основной вопрос - почему...

```
public interface SubscriberMapper
{
    @Select("select * from subscriber where id = #{id};")
    Subscriber getSubscriberById(Integer id);

    @Select("select * from subscriber;")
    List<Subscriber> getSubscribers();
}
```

Comment: На всякий случай проверил, соединение с базой данных проходит. Во всяком случае при подключении с использованием "чистого" jdbc вопросы из мапперов проходят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас всё перемешалось. Если вы используете маппинг в xml-конфигурации, то конструкция `mapper` в **mybatis-config.xml** должна выглядеть так:

```
<mapper resource="SubscriberMapper.xml"/>
```

А сам **SubscriberMapper.xml** так:

```
<mapper namespace="com.example.SubscriberMapper">
    <resultMap id="subscriber" type="com.example.Subscriber" />

    <select id="getSubscriberById" parameterType="java.lang.Integer" resultMap="subscriber">
        select * from subscriber where id = #{id}  
    </select>

    <select id="getSubscribers" resultMap="subscriber">
        select * from subscriber
    </select>
</mapper>
```

А тег `<resources>` из **pom.xml** удалите, от греха подальше.

Comment: Исправил, заработало!
Действительно, я сейчас еще не усвоил у себя в голове полной картины того, как все работает и пытаясь собрать работающий код по разным "туториалам" в конец запутался.
Большое Вам спасибо!
Не могли бы Вы только уточнить, почему <resources> лучше от греха из pom.xml удалить?

Comment: Потому, что не нужен.

Comment: Понял
Ещё раз, большое спасибо.